# Why pointer is not null after function call?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm not often using C++ an do I'm currently having a problem with pointers using Microsoft C++.
I have defined a half edge data structure. Code sample shows a part of the structure.

```
struct edge
{
    HalfEdge    *he1;   // pointer to right halfedge
    HalfEdge    *he2;   // pointer to left halfedge 
    Edge        *nexte; // pointer to next edge
    Edge        *preve; // pointer to previous edge
};

struct halfedge
{
    Edge        *edg;   // pointer to parent edge
    Vertex      *vtx;   // pointer to starting vertex 
    Loop        *wloop; // back pointer to loop
    HalfEdge    *nexthe;// pointer to next halfedge
    HalfEdge    *prevhe;// pointer to previous halfedge
};
```

Now I have initalized the variables of Edge with NULL.
I work with edge in a method.

```
void CDataStructureBuilder::create4VertFace(Face* f,Vertex* v1,Vertex* v2, Vertex* v3, Vertex* v4,Edge* e1,Edge* e2,Edge* e3,Edge* e4){
    Loop outerLoop;

    createHalfEdges(v1,v2,e1);  
    createHalfEdges(v2,v3,e2);
    createHalfEdges(v3,v4,e3);  
    createHalfEdges(v4,v1,e4);  


    outerLoop.lface = f;
    outerLoop.ledge = e1->he2;

    connectEdges(e1, e2);
    connectEdges(e2, e3);
    connectEdges(e3, e4);
    connectEdges(e4, e1);
```

If I use the debugger I see that the variables he1 and he2 of e1 contains 0x000000. Now I call the following function.

void CDataStructureBuilder::createHalfEdges(Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2, Edge* ed){
        if (ed->he2==NULL){
            HalfEdge* h = new HalfEdge();
            h->vtx = v1;
            h->edg = ed;
            ed->he2 = h;
        }
        if (!(ed->he1)){
            HalfEdge* h = new HalfEdge();
            h->vtx = v2;
            h->edg = ed;
            ed->he1 = h;
        }
    }

Now, if I use the debugger, the pointer ed has the same address but the variables he2 and he1 not longer contains 0x000000. They contain 0xccccccc. So the if-condition ed->he2==NULL in method createHalfEdges is false.

Can anybody tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Additional Info:
The outer method of create4VertFace is doing the following:

```
Vertex* vertices;
vertices = createVertices();

Edge* edges;
edges = createEdges();

create4VertFace(&bottom, &vertices[0], &vertices[1], &vertices[2], &vertices[3], &(edges[0]), &(edges[1]), &(edges[2]), &(edges[3]));
```

In `createedges` I have defined the edges in the following way. Is this perhaps the mistake?

```
Edge* CDataStructureBuilder::createEdges(void){
    Edge edgelist[24]; 

    Edge e0t1 = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
    // ...
    edgelist[0] = e0t1;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
   HalfEdge h;
   ...
   ed->he2 = &h;
```

`h` goes out of scope when you exit the enclosing block. As a result `ed->he2`, while keeping its value, becomes a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

One way to fix it is by allocating the `HalfEdge` instance on the heap (using `new`).

**edit:** It looks like `createEdges()` has the same bug: it creates a pointer to `e0t1`. The latter lives on the stack and goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: but why the condition in if is always false? that imho has nothing to do with the HalfEdge h. I first want to check if the variables ed->he2 and ed->he1 have already an adress and if not i want to add the necessary data. If I copy the if-condition to the outer method and use e1 everything works fine.

Comment: @martin: Show us more code. You might also be making the same mistake someplace else.

Comment: @martin: Does `createEdges` return `edgelist`? If so, it looks like the same problem - you've got a pointer to `e0t1` that lives on the stack and disappears when you exit the function.

Comment: I think, I have solved the problem. It was as you have described. I've changed edgelist to the type Edge** and worked with this. Thank's very much!

Answer (score 1):

0xCC is used by Visual C++ compiler to fill uninitialized data. Most probably `ed` was pointing to a temporary object that was created on stack, and its contents were destroyed later and got overwritten during next calls.

Note that `ed->he2 = &h;` also takes address of temporary object `h`, this is just the same mistake that screws the `ed`'s contents.